# Automatic network troubleshooting in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

The ethernet drivers of my motherboard (Gigabyte B550I) seem to be rather finicky, and I often need to reset the network adapter after rebooting my machine to make it operate properly.

Using the Windows 10 "Troubleshoot problems" feature almost always solves the issue. However, I currently need to go and do this manually every time the problem occurs.

Now I'm wondering -- as a workaround in the absence of better drivers, is there any way I could get Windows to automatically run this troubleshooting flow when the connection is down?

Comment: I'd consider a PCI NIC. $£€ 20 even for a decent one. Set & forget after that.

Comment: The B550I is a mini-ITX motherboard, so my only expansion slot is spent on the GPU :-)